# Library (or manual creation) of ERP components

Tags: computational-modeling, eeg, neuroimaging, brain-waves, signal-processing

I'm looking to test some computational models using ERP components as inputs (eg. p300, n170)

I'm wondering if there is an existing library anywhere that would have a bank of wave/component examples that I could download?

Or alternatively, maybe preferably, is there any useable Python or R code that I could use to just generate these types of waves/components?

Comment: Start here in meantime: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ERP/ERP.pdf